# WebView CustomScrollView + Floating AppBar

Tags: webview, flutter, flutter-sliver, flutter-appbar

I am trying to create a screen that has a WebView (from [webview_flutter: ^0.3.5+3](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/webview_flutter)) and an `AppBar` that I want to scroll offscreen on user scroll.

I stumbled upon this [guide](https://flutterdoc.com/animating-app-bars-in-flutter-cf034cd6c68b) and tried implementing something similar, but no dice.
Is there a way to use a `WebView` in a `CustomScrollView` with `Slivers` or is this not supported yet?

I can get the scrolling app bar to work if I create regular Widgets in my `SliverChildListDelegate` (I tried `Row`, `Text`, `Container` etc.), but had no luck with a `WebView`.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            title: const Text("Heading"),
            floating: true,
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
              Container(
                child: WebView(
                  initialUrl: url,
                  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                ),
              )
            ]
            ),
          )
        ],
      )
  );
}
```

Any pointers/suggestions/RTFMs welcome.

**EDIT BOUNTY**

The solution provided by jordan-davies works but is very choppy.
Whenever the `SliverAppBar` is scrolled away the `WebView` tries to resize itself to fill the remaining viewport. This makes for a very choppy/slow experience.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return CustomScrollView(
    slivers: <Widget>[
      SliverAppBar(
        title: const Text("Heading"),
        floating: true,
      ),
      SliverFillRemaining(
        child: WebView(initialUrl: "http://stackoverflow.com"),
      )
    ],
  );
}
```

[image: gif of code above]
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I actually wanted to make a comment but it is too long to fit

I can give you my view for why it is not possible to do that with the current state of the plugin ,by default the `Webview` only respond to drag gesture when no other views claim that gesture.
 On the other hand, Scrolling slivers like `SliverList`, which is needed to make the `SliverAppBar`  to scroll up ,by default consumes all drag scrolling gestures -*although you can disable that by providing noScrollPhysics* - but once the `WebView` cover all the screen there is actually noway to report back to the slivers to start consume scroll again .

So the solution is to modify the `WebView plugin` itself to provide a callback for drag gestures , hope that flutter team will implement this feature soon.

Comment: I have opened up an official bug report on Github; https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31243

Comment: If you upvote the chances are higher they address the issue first.

Comment: @tim done, please check my answer there it has a partial solution

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at using a `SliverFillRemaining` or `SliverFillViewport` instead of `SliverList`. Heres an example using `SliverFillRemaining`

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SliverFillRemaining-class.html

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar(
          title: const Text("Heading"),
          floating: true,
        ),
        SliverFillRemaining(
          child: WebView(initialUrl: "http://stackoverflow.com"),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. That renders the WebView but the CustomScrollView seems to be consuming all the scroll events past the point where the AppBar scrolls off the screen. I'm sure there's a way to delegate the scroll events to the WebView at that point, but my flutter-fu is not up there. Going to try SliverFillViewport now.

Comment: No luck with SilverFillViewport either. The WebView renders but when you scroll the WebView is duplicated past the point where the original WebView's bounds ended. I think, based on the docs, the SliverChildBuilderDelegate is called back once you go beyond the initial viewport to lazily create more children. What I see on the screen seems to suggest this is happening. So I am back where I was.

Comment: Hmm might not be possible with a `WebView` then. I've been playing around with using a `NestedScrollView` instead of the `CustomScrollView` but can't get it to work. Theres a good example [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/NestedScrollView-class.html) if you want to have a play.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: I tried the provided solution but it seems like the webview tries to resize when the appbar is scrolling out of view. Which makes it a really choppy/slow experience.
I have a put a bounty on the question.

Answer (score 0):

After many trial and errors I found a way to fix a similar issue by using `gestureRecognizers` like so :

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliverFillRemaining(
      child: WebView(
        initialUrl: url,
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        gestureRecognizers: {
          Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
            () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer(),
          ),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```